openpyxl. Очистить функцию excel, оставив только значение яйчейки
у меня есть эксель таблица, в которую с помощью openpyxl записывается число, которое используется во многих функциях. Вообще сказали считать всё вручную, но я сделаю через функции, так что при сохранении файла, нужно оставить лишь только итоговые значения:
Пример:

в А2 записывается число 80
в яйчейке A3 функция "=ОКРУГЛВНИЗ((A2*36%)/2,5;0)*2,5"
И нужно, чтобы в яйчейке оставалось только итоговое число "27,5"


И в чем проблема?

В написании кода, сам не знаю как писать, а Chat GPT не может это выполнить

Это всё-таки не фриланс, за вас тут бесплатно код писать никто не будет. Так что если сами не хотите вникать, то никакой гпт вам и не поможет.
